# How should I conditionally include jsp depending on the clicked URL?

Tags: spring, jsp

I'm trying to construct a page consisting of at least a header, a footer and a *"main content area"* in between, where content is conditionally included, depending on the clicked url.

I'm thinking that an index page should contain code to include the header and the footer, which would always stay the same. The content in between those should depend on the clicked url.

Currently I'm using `<sec:authorize access="isAuthenticated()">` for *some* conditions, like whether to display a login or logout link in the navbar. This is fine for minor difference between pagess, but would become unmanageable for pages with totally different content.

Currently, the way my controller is set up, I'm redirecting the user to a totally new page when they click a link (see below). This seems like a waste because I have to include the header and footer on every single page - plus any other design elements that should remain the same.

How should I go about this? Or should I do this in some different way?

Current setup, using Spring:

```
@RequestMapping(value = {"/"})
public String landingPage() {
    logger.info("landingPage called");
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping("/user_register")
public ModelAndView registerUser() {
    logger.info("registerUser called");
    ModelAndView model = new ModelAndView();
    User user = new User();
    model.addObject(user);
    model.setViewName("userRegistrationForm");
    return model;
}

...
```

Comment: Templating frameworks like [Apache Tiles](https://tiles.apache.org/) or [Thymeleaf](http://www.thymeleaf.org/) already solve this problem for you.